# atribuir ultimo campo de uma tabela a um input text

Tags: php, mysql, input, text

Tenho um tabela que guarda os abastecimentos de um veículo e gostaria de fazer o seguinte código funcionar. Preciso pegar o último registro com a quilometragem do odômetro e já trazer pro input text específico, chamado kmAnterior. Tem que ser o último campo, pra eu descobrir o caminho percorrido. Exemplo: kmAnterior 115,  kmAtual 215. Cálculo (kmAtual - kmAnterior) = 100 km. Então o atual eu vou digitar, e gostaria que o anterior buscasse automaticamente na tabela (último registro gravado). Estou fazendo de uma forma que não está funcionando:

```
<input type="text" name = "kmAnterior" placeholder = "KM Anterior" value = "<?php echo $linha['kmAbastecimento']; ?>">
```

Onde esse `$linha` é a forma que estou usando pra preencher uma tabela (usando while). Quero conseguir pegar sempre o último valor da tabela e lançar diretamente nesse campo, de uma forma mais limpa e simples possível, pois a tabela tem uma série de outros cálculos.

Comment: Qual estrutura da tabela? Como é o seu SELECT? A principio isso pode resolver `SELECT * FROM [TABELA] ORDER BY [CAMPO] DESC LIMIT 1`  ou então `select max(campo_id) from tabela`

Comment: Supondo haver um id auto-incremento pode ser assim `select * from tabela
where id = (select max(id) from tabela)`